# Can U-Boot boot scripts have comments?

Tags: comments, u-boot

I'm writing a U-Boot boot script, and I'd like to clarify why a specific address is used exactly. However, I've not been able to find any documentation on how to write comments in U-Boot boot scripts, or if this is possible at all. Is it possible for U-Boot boot scripts to have comments, and if so, how do I write comments in them?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by *"boot script"*.  Are you referring to the value of an environment variable such as `bootcmd`?  If you build U-Boot to use the Hush shell (instead of the simple command-line parser), then `#` will start a comment.

Comment: @sawdust I'm not sure what U-Boot formally calls it, but the kind of script you build into script images with `$ mkimage -T script ...`.

Comment: If your U-Boot is configured with the Hush parser, then you can use `#` to start a comment.  Otherwise you could resort to using an `echo` command.  BTW such U-Boot commands in a text file are simply referred to as a [script image](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootScripts), and the script image is "executed" with the `source` command.